# B-ship game: X's and O's are just screwing up. (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a game of [B-ship](http://bit.ly/1uSAjnB), and I am unable to get the placements to work out.

The hits don't stay there after i call another hit.

So far this is user side only.

Here's my code.

```
def drawboard(hitboard):
    print('|   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + hitboard[7] + ' | ' + hitboard[8] + ' | ' + hitboard[9] + ' |')
    print('|   |   |   |')
    print('-------------')
    print('|   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + hitboard[4] + ' | ' + hitboard[5] + ' | ' + hitboard[6] + ' |')
    print('|   |   |   |')
    print('-------------')
    print('|   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + hitboard[1] + ' | ' + hitboard[2] + ' | ' + hitboard[3] + ' |')
    print('|   |   |   |')

def aiships(hitboard):
    hitboard[1], hitboard[2], hitboard[3] = ' ',' ',' '
    #One of the AI's ships

def aicorners(hitboard,spot_hit):
    if hitboard[spot_hit] == hitboard[1] or  hitboard[spot_hit] == hitboard[2] or  hitboard[spot_hit] == hitboard[3]:
        hitboard[spot_hit] = 'x'
    else:
        hitboard[spot_hit] = 'o'
    print(drawboard(hitboard))

def aiedges(hitboard,spot_hit):
    if hitboard[spot_hit] == hitboard[1] or  hitboard[spot_hit] == hitboard[2] or  hitboard[spot_hit] == hitboard[3]:
        hitboard[spot_hit] = 'x'
    else:
        hitboard[spot_hit] = 'o'

    print(drawboard(hitboard))

def aimiddle(hitboard,spot_hit):
    if hitboard[spot_hit] == hitboard[1] or  hitboard[spot_hit] == hitboard[2] or  hitboard[spot_hit] == hitboard[3]:
        hitboard[spot_hit] = 'x'
    else:
        hitboard[spot_hit] = 'o'

    print(drawboard(hitboard))

def main():
    gameisplaying = True
    while gameisplaying:
        hitboard = [' ']* 10
        userready = input('Place your ships. Type done when you finished placing it.')
        while not userready == 'done':
            userready = input('Type done when you locate your ship.  ')
        shipissunk = False
        while shipissunk == False:
            spot_hit = input('Where\'s the hit?: 1-9  ')
            while not (spot_hit in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split()):
                spot_hit = input ('Please tell me where the hit is: 1-9  ')
            spot_hit = int(spot_hit)
            x = aiships(hitboard)
            if (spot_hit in [1,3,7,9]):
                aicorners(hitboard,spot_hit)
            elif (spot_hit in [2,4,6,8]):
                aiedges(hitboard,spot_hit)
            else:
                aimiddle(hitboard,spot_hit)

main()
```

You are supposed to get your own piece of paper. When you place your ships on your IRL paper, you type 'done' and then you guess the computer's ships.

I put in 2 and it showed up as X, which is good. Putting in 3 erases the previous X and puts an X in 3, so there's still only 1 X. That is not good. However, when I put it in 4,5,6,7,8 or 9, it stays, but Some are X's (not good) and some are O's (good). X = hit O = miss

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One mistake (maybe there are others) is declaring:

```
hitboard = [' ']* 10
```

by doing so, you create "10 cells" which all point to the same place `" "`. When "one" changes - so will all the others.

Use instead:

```
hitboard = [' ' for i in range(10)]
```

Another mistake is the function `aiships()`, it's messing with places 1,2 and 3. simply remove the following lines:

```
def aiships(hitboard):
    hitboard[1], hitboard[2], hitboard[3] = ' ',' ',' '
    #One of the AI's ships
```

and:

```
x = aiships(hitboard)
```

Comment: Thank's for answering, but it's still the same problem, like the X is being moved around on 1, 2, and 3

Comment: awesome! I think it's good for now! I'll open a new one if anything else comes up.