# B-ship game follow up 2: AI and User IDK how to do alternating turns

Tags: python, python-3.x

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512486/b-ship-game-xs-and-os-are-just-screwing-up-python)

I have been making a b-ship game but I have run into a problem. It is 3x3, so it's a scaled down version of the actual game. We're using one ship for now.

I currently have the user hitting the AI section done, but how can i make it switch to the Ai's turn after one hit?

The AI, when it is his turn, knows that the user has part of a ship at [4] and that will stay that way for now. then He tries to hit [7], but if that doesn't work, try [1], or if that doesn't work, try [5]. And How can I do this for any edge??

```
import random

def drawboard(hitboard,hitboard2):
    print(' Opponent\'s          Your')
    print('    Ships            Ships')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + hitboard[7] + ' | ' + hitboard[8] + ' | ' + hitboard[9] + ' |    | ' + hitboard2[7] + ' | ' + hitboard2[8] + ' | ' + hitboard2[9] + ' |')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('-------------    -------------')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + hitboard[4] + ' | ' + hitboard[5] + ' | ' + hitboard[6] + ' |    | ' + hitboard2[4] + ' | ' + hitboard2[5] + ' | ' + hitboard2[6] + ' |')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('-------------    -------------')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + hitboard[1] + ' | ' + hitboard[2] + ' | ' + hitboard[3] + ' |    | ' + hitboard2[1] + ' | ' + hitboard2[2] + ' | ' + hitboard2[4] + ' |')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
def aiships(hitboard,spot_hit,shipspots,hitboard2):
    if spot_hit in shipspots:
        hitboard[1] = 'x'
    else:
        hitboard[7] = 'o'
    drawboard(hitboard,hitboard2)

def playerships(hitboard,hitboard2, spot_hit, usershipspots):
    hitboard2[7] = 'x'
    print("\nComputer's turn.\n")
    spot_hit = random.choice(usershipspots)
    hitboard2[spot_hit] = 'x'
    if spot_hit not in usershipspots:
        hitboard2[spot_hit] = 'o'
    drawboard(hitboard,hitboard2)

def main():
    possiblespots = [[1,2],[2,3],[4,5],[5,6],[7,8],[8,9],[1,4],[4,7],[2,5],[5,8],[3,6],[6,9]]
    shipspots = random.choice(possiblespots)

    userspots = [[4,7],[4,1],[4,5]]
    usershipspots = random.choice(userspots)
    gameisplaying = True
    ai_spots = [4, 7, 1, 5]
    ai_index = 0
    while gameisplaying:
        hitboard = [' ' for i in range(10)]
        hitboard2 = [' ' for i in range(10)]
        hitboard2[usershipspots[0]] = 's'
        hitboard2[usershipspots[1]] = 's'
        userready = input('Place your ships. Type done when you finished placing it.')
        while not userready == 'done':
            userready = input('Type done when you locate your ship.  ')
        spot_hit = input('Where\'s the hit?: 1-9  ')
        while not (spot_hit in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split()):
            spot_hit = input ('Please tell me where the hit is: 1-9  ')
        spot_hit = int(spot_hit)
        aiships(hitboard, spot_hit, shipspots, hitboard2)
        playerships(hitboard, hitboard2, ai_spots[ai_index], shipspots)
        ai_index += 1

main()
```

But wait, there's more! (billy mays reference)

No matter what number I put in, there will always be an O in the 7 space. Unless I put in the ship coordinates of the playerships (which is quite odd) which will create an X in the 1 space. Also there will always be an 's' in the 3 space on the 'your ships' board. (using numpad for numbers)

Comment: On the "annoying `None`", sure -- change the `print(drawboard(hitboard,hitboard2))` calls to simple `drawboard(hitboard,hitboard2)` calls and it will be gone.  On the other issue, I'm not sure I understand it!  I don't understand how the user is telling you where he's placed his ships &c.  As for having the `AI` determine where to shoot next, why not start simple: pick a random spot the AI hasn't shot before.  "doing this for any edge" leaves me totally perplexed as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok let me rephrase. This is for an assignment and we haven't actually started the final game. it's a first trial with a partial portion of the actual game. User has one ship. (final we will have 2) and computer has 1, final 2. The teacher said to assume the computer already got a hit in 4, which is what i have here. Then what would it do next to try to sink it?

Comment: i'm trying to create that, but in my code (see above) it just has a bunch of x's and s's in the board. The left board is the hits and misses you placed which we're not worrying about right now. the right board is the user's ships. It is in spot 4,7 or 4,1 or 4,5 chosen at random. Why the X's are there? i dont know. @AlexMartelli

Comment: In `aiships` you're always setting `hitboard[1]` or `hitboard[7]` no matter the `spot_hit` -- I have no idea why.  In `playerships` you're still ignoring the `spot_hit` argument now so carefully constructed -- again, no idea why.

Comment: Then how can I solve this problem? @AlexMartelli

Comment: Since I have no idea of why you're doing the peculiar things you're doing, I'm not well placed to explain what you should be doing instead!-)

Comment: We are not worrying about user hitting AI, we only worry about AI hitting user for now,

Comment: The user's ship has 3 possible locations, [4,7] [4,1] [4,5]

Comment: and then the AI has gotten a hit in spot 4 alreaDy

Comment: @AlexMartelli SO what would AI do next to try to sink the ship?

Comment: SO is starting to scold us "Please avoid extended discussions in comments".  I have no time for chats, so, just open another Q!  And remove absurd statements from `playerships` such as the leading `hitboard2[7] = 'x'` (?!) and the middling `spot_hit = random.choice(usershipspots)` which have absolutely no reason for existing.  More generally, every statement you write should be there for a reason -- far too much useless, damaging, incomprehensible statements in your code so far.

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530514/b-ship-follow-up-code-is-just-overall-messed-up) my new question. @AlexMartelli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So between the two current statements

```
aiships(hitboard,spot_hit,shipspots,hitboard2)
playerships(hitboard, hitboard2,spot_hit,shipspots)
```

you need to recompute `spot_hit` so it's 4 the first time, then 7, then 1, then 5 (we'll worry about "any hedge" in some other future Q, OK?-).

For the purpose, it's simplest to initialize, just before the `while`:

```
ai_spots = [4, 7, 1, 5]
ai_index = 0
```

and then transform those two statements into:

```
aiships(hitboard, spot_hit, shipspots, hitboard2)
playerships(hitboard, hitboard2, ai_spots[ai_index], shipspots)
ai_index += 1
```

I hope it's clear how it works here.  BTW, a side note, the randomly different order of arguments in the two functions is confusing to no good purpose -- reorder things so that they're the same in both cases!

For the "all hedges" presumably you need a longer list for `ai_spots` and the ability to increment `ai_index` by more than one if an attempt was not successful -- which in turn requires `playerships` to give you a boolean return telling you if the attempt was successful or not, so you can use it to determine how much to change `ai_index` by.

However that's very premature as you still have many bigger bugs to think about right now.  For example, consider the snippet:

```
spot_hit = random.choice(usershipspots)
if spot_hit in usershipspots:
```

`random.choice` **always** returns one of the items in its argument -- so the check of whether its return value is indeed one of those items is completely redundant -- it will always be `True` and the body of the `if` clause will always execute.

No doubt you want to remove that recomputation of `spot_hit` as a random choice and accept the argument you're passed instead!

The `if` can remain of course and at the end of the function you can `return spot_hit in usershipspots` which is exactly the boolean telling you if the hit was successful or not.

Comment: Excellent answer! I am working on breaking it down. I am assuming that this is the order that you want me to tackle it in.

Comment: Please see my edit. I will post screenies of me running the program if you want it.

Comment: @interwebz, I'm not looking at new Qs until and unless this A gets accepted (thus clearly marking this "phase" of the Q&A as completed).